# SQL Server Null Logical XOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, xor

I'm creating a constraint on a (Microsoft) Sql Server 2008 table.  I have two columns that are different datatypes.  One column must be null at all times, but not both (A logical exclusive OR/XOR).  I have a working expression currently.

```
(@a is null or @b is null) and not (@a is null and @b is null)
```

My question is **Is there a cleaner or shorter way to write this code?**

To test it you can use this code...

```
declare @a int
declare @b varchar(5)

set @a=1
set @b='XXXXX'

if (@a is null or @b is null) and not (@a is null and @b is null)
  select 'pass'
else
  select 'fail'
```

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server, not postgresql.  The syntax does not support "!=".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer

```
if (@a is null and @b is not null) or (@a is not null and @b is null)
```

It is a little clearer in my opinion

Comment: Beat me to an almost identical post by 30 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @SQLMenace +1. thanks for pointing out my mistake without downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is a (albeit stupid) suggestion if you are working with all strings. And it scales to multiples greater than 2 where you want a particular number of non-nulls. Again, its stupid and not really shorter but it was too fun to pass up mentioning...

```
where LEN(ISNULL(right(@a+'x',1),'')+ISNULL(right(@b+'x',1),'')) = 1
```

To make it work with your stuff, You'd have to CAST the [int], I suppose.  Doing string "surgery" in the where clause before matching is evil and liable to be real slow. But if you had 6 columns and needed exactly 1 to be not-null this trick would scale up.

Basically, we're using LEN to count the not-nulls. The `+'x'` ensures that you don't count a `''` as null. You could leave that off when testing [char] columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather choose this

```
if IIF( @a is null, 0, 1 ) <> IIF( @b is null, 0, 1 )
```